# How to close application on onBackPressed() in home activity

Tags: java, android

How to close application on `onBackPressed()` in home activity.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "close application"? When the user presses BACK, by default, your activity will be destroyed. Your `onBackPressed()` method is preventing that.

Comment: Why are you starting a new Activity, when you want to close the application? Consider using super.onBackpressed to finish the activity

Answer (score 2):

Use the below code in your home activity (MainActivity):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Did this solved your problem? Or u want something other?